# RSA authentication works for one user but not another

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to setup SSH authentication via RSA files on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.
I generated key files on my local machine, then used

```
ssh-add  ./id_rsa
```

and copied id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys then changed permissions

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.
```

It works fine for one user, I type ssh user@host on my local machine and it connects automatically without asking password. But when I do all the same steps for another user, ssh asks for a password and after three unsuccessful login attempts it writes

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: The keys must existing the .ssh directory of each users i.e. /home/<username>/.ssh

Comment: They do. I have the same ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file with the same permissions in both users' home directories.

Comment: Did you change ownership of the file? What do you have in sshd logfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in ownership of the file. I've changed owner of ~/.ssh directory to the user, which I tried to login as, and passwordless access began to work.

Comment: you should accept your own answer